# Is it possible to use AcuGIS with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cloud-gis

Has anyone use **[AcuGIS](http://www.acugis.com/)**, a web hosting service for PostGIS and GeoServe?  I am curious to see how it works with QGIS.  I am looking at some cloud hosting services for PostGIS and I would like to be able to access the database in QGIS and pgAdmin.  Has anyone had any success or issues with AcuGIS.  Or can you recommend any other cloud hosting services.

Answer (score 6):

I have purchased a month with AcuGIS and the connection, speed, and ease of connection is great with QGIS.  It is a simple option for cloud PostGIS hosting.

Comment: As a side note, this company is terrible. Horrible customer service, very unprofessional. They are still billing me 9 months after I closed my account. Wanted everyone to know about them before you get yourself into a bad situation.

Comment: This may have been the case with AcuGIS in 2015, but it definitely has not been my experience in 2019. In fact, the company CTO jumped in on some issues I was having (all due to my Unix amnesia after 20 years away from it...) and personally resolved them. The service is quick, reliable and *very* cost-effective.